# NUnit testing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nunit

I added unit test to my method but I get an error. The method is working; outside the test, it works 100%.

```
 public async Task ClearCartAsync()
    {
        var carts = _cartRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        for (var i = 0; i < carts.Count; i++)
        {
            var sub = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(carts.ElementAt(i).PurchaseDate);
            var minutes = sub.Minutes;
            var hours = sub.Hours;
            if (Math.Abs(hours) > 0 || Math.Abs(minutes) > 1)
            {
                var seatId = carts.ElementAt(i).EventSeatId;
                var seat = await _eventSeatRepository.GetByIdAsync(seatId); //problem here
                seat.State = EventSeatState.Empty;
                await _eventSeatRepository.UpdateAsync(seat);
                await _cartRepository.DeleteAsync(carts.ElementAt(i).Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
Next step.

```
/// <summary>Gets an awaiter used to await this <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1" />.</summary>
/// <returns>An awaiter instance.</returns>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public TaskAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter()
{
  return new TaskAwaiter<TResult>(this);
}
```

and next: seat = null;

Why doesn't it go to the method?

UPD:

EventSeatRepository:

```
public override async Task<EventSeatEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await base.GetByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

GenericRepository:

```
  public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying `await _eventSeatRepository.GetByIdAsync(seatId)` is returning `null`, such that `seat.State` blows up? Can we see your test method?

Comment: The problem is that the debugger is not included in the getById method, it immediately return new TaskAwaiter <TResult> (this);

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why that is, but I think it will be easier to help if we can see how `eventSeatRepository` and the test method looks

Comment: Added eventRepo and GenericRepo

Comment: Since the test is what isn't working, please include the code of the test.